# Bugs in Visual Studio 2010/Weird For-Loop behaviour?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I was just shocked when my application fired an IndexOutOfRanage exception now. I opened the *Debugger Locals Pane* and discovered that my integer crossed it's boundary? Basically I have something like this in my code:

```
string folder = Extender.GetSetting<string>("textFolder");
string mlink = folder + "\\" + filename + ".txt";
if(File.Exists(mlink))
{
    string fContent = File.ReadAllText(mlink);
    rtbLearnGuide.Text = fContent;
    string[] strings = fContent.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++, words.Enqueue(strings[i]));
}
```

The problem here is that i reaches the length of `strings[]`, I have attached a picture below.

[image: Weird For-Loop behaviour]

What's even more weird is that I failed to reproduce this behavior a second time.

**NB:** I experienced something similar earlier today with `this.CreateGraphics();` My code was something like:

```
var dc = this.CreateGraphics();//and some other stuff
```

*The result was that it failed to draw it even after trying to rerun like 4 times, then I went back to the code and defined dc explicitly, voila it was working. Then I changed it back to var, it was still working :/?*

What might be wrong?

**EDIT:**

I just discovered that changing the order works. For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; words.Enqueue(strings[i]), i++);
```

**doesn't fire** any errors.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to write the for-loop the way most developers would expect?

Comment: `<sarcasm>`If you're into combining statements, why stop at what you've done?  `words.Enqueue(strings[i++])` `</sarcasm>` but then @CodeNaked's question really comes into play.

Comment: Not exactly, this is actually just a discovery for me, didn't know multiple for loop statements are executed backwards...

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata, they're not executed backwards.  With your updated code `words.Enqueue(strings[i])` runs first then the increment `i++` runs second.

Comment: I must have drank some dead coffee, thanks for that @heavyd !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, you are executing the Enqueue *before* the for loop's test condition. So

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++, words.Enqueue(strings[i]));
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++) words.Enqueue(strings[i]);
```

Basically, the "increment" portion will always execute before the "test" portion.

Comment: Eh, no. Actually, you can have multiple statements in a for loop, apart from just incrementing.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - Yes, but they will execute *before* the test portion as I said.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata, you're also skipping the 0th element in your array doing it that way.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you but you can still have the test portion inside. I used to code this way, so I just swapped the position to: `for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; words.Enqueue(strings[i]), i++);` and it works.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata You shouldn't do that though; that's not following the very well established convention of how to use a `for` loop.  The body of the loop should be in the body of the loop, not embedded in the "move next" section.  It's just bad practice, regardless of whether or not it works.

Answer (score 5):

Format your for loop logically and you will not have that error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    words.Enqueue(strings[i]);
```

In your code, "i" is incremented past the condition (strings.Length) you are THEN running the word.Enqueue on an out of bounds "i".

Your loop (in pseudo code):

```
i = 0
Loop_Label:
IF i >= strings.Length THEN GoTo End_Label
... where the for loop body should go ...
i = i + 1
words.Enqueue strings[i]
GoTo Loop_Label
End_Label:
```

Comment: Well, I don't really understand what you mean by *logically*.. Thanks though

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata By "logically", he means based on the very well established standard practice of how to format a `for` loop that is very tightly ingrained in the minds of most all programmers, to such a degree that violating it is highly illogical.